# Reading and writing to a file in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, read-write

So, I am a beginner in assembly and my teacher gave us a practice problem to try out ourselves.There is a text file storing data of students like this:

```
1 23 45
2 43 41
.......
.......
```

The first column is for the roll no. of the student, the second column is for the marks scored by him/her in the 1st subject and the third column is for the marks scored by him/her in the 2nd subject.We're supposed to find the sum of the marks scored by every student and store in a fourth column.So, the final text file should look somewhat like this:

```
1 23 45 68
2 43 41 84
..........
..........
```

Here are the problems being encountered by me:
1.How do I find the number of lines in the file? (for the loop)
2.How to I read the marks in the two subjects?
3.After reading from a particular line, how do I jump to the next line?

I know how to do simple read,write operations from a file but this one,I just cannot start.I would appreciate if someone would come to my rescue.Thanks in advance.
Please note that I have to write the code using MASM.

Comment: Think about how you'd do it in a higher-level language, like C.  Don't get caught up in the low-level implementation details until you have a big-picture idea of what you want to happen to the data.  Notice that each line is independent, so you don't need to remember anything about previous lines, or total line counts.  The big question is if you can use standard library string functions (like scanf/printf) to parse the file and format output, or if you can only use block read/write functions.

Comment: Oh, are you one of those people that think the only way to loop is with a counter in ecx counting down to zero?  You can actually loop on any condition you want, e.g. the stop when your read function / system call gives an EOF.